# What is the meaning of this question to be? What will be the meaning of this question?

Tags: sentence-construction

> What is the meaning of this question to be?
>   What will be the meaning of this question?

Which one is correct? 
Clarify the difference between them.

Comment: Is there anyone who can clear my concept?

Comment: As for the other question: I recommend you read [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) on meta and clarify your question.

Comment: Stephie,  Sir . I am confused.  How to ask the question with proper way,  please guide me.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. 1. We like to know why you are asking the question (we call this **context**) - was it a sentence in a book, an exercise at school or you are just wondering which is the correct way to say something. This leads directly to 2. We must know what the question is: Tell us, in your own words, what you want to say. Don't worry, if your English is bad, we can understand a lot or we will ask you to explain. At the moment, your questions are a bit like "Is 3 or 17 the correct answer?" We need to know the question. 3. Tell us, what you *think* or what you found in a dictionary.

Comment: Your questions are "on hold", that means *not* that you can't ask, but you need edit them to make them better *matching the rules here*. Then we can re-open them. Before you edit, read some questions on this site and see how they do points 1-3 from my comment above. If you need examples, I can point you there. Again: did you read [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)?

Comment: Sir please tell me your I.d name on Facebook.  I would share my problems with you there.  Please please sir

Comment: I feel difficulty here.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you more than this - we are no "teaching" or "coaching" site. Even my many comments here and at your other question need to be removed, comments are not for discussion. I can't access chat from my computer else we could discuss your questions there. Perhaps another time.

Comment: Ok , Sir.  I will try to share my problems with you.  I will share my questions here.  You are requested to correct me always.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the questions are oddly phrased. No English speaker would say:

> What is the meaning of this question to be?

Although it is understandable that you are asking a question about the future meaning of a question that you are asking. Why would you ask a question about the meaning of a question in the future? Also, putting the infinitive "to be" at the end of a question is not usually used in English, perhaps not at all. The latter question sounds more natural.

As for the other question:

> What will be the meaning of this question?

This too is oddly phrased because it is strange to ask someone about the future meaning of a question. Asking "What will be the meaning ... " is asking someone to predict the meaning of a question at some point in time. It's better to ask "What is the meaning of this question?" because you are asking about the meaning "now", not in the future.

Comment: Alger,  You are begged to solve my previous questions which have been shared by me .